# Having trouble manipulating axis.text (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I saw an graphic on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/6f0tq0/biggest_airlines_in_the_united_states_oc/) and have been working on recreating it.  However I am having trouble configuring the axis.text into a more legible format and was wondering what some possible solutions might be.

The code that I have come up with so far is:

```
    library(ggplot2) 
    library(forcats) 

    airlines <- c('Delta', 'American', 'Spirit', 'JetBlue', 'Alaska', 'United', 'Southwest') 

    market_cap <- c(37100000000,25300000000, 3400000000, 7000000000, 9000000000, 21000000000, 25800000000)

    airline_industry <- data.frame(airlines, market_cap)

    ggplot(airline_industry, aes(fct_reorder(airlines, market_cap), market_cap)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    labs(title = "Biggest US Airline Companies by Market Cap", y = 'Market Capitalization (USD)') + 
    coord_flip() + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c('10000000000' = '10B', '20000000000' = '20B', '30000000000' = '30B'))
```

So the problem I am having is that my breaks along the x axis manually lists out 10, 20, & 30 billion in digit form, which looks messy.  I am trying to figure out how to represent the breaks with 10B, 20B, and 30B.  Similar to the example to the reddit example that was shared above.  scale_x_discrete doesn't appear to be working.  What would be the correct way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1e10, 2e10, 3e10), labels = c('0B', '10B', '20B', '30B'))
```

A bit confusing perhaps to use a `y` scale here, but that is due to `coord_flip`; your original aesthetic mapping is `market_cap -> y`.

Then note that that axis is continuous, not discrete.

Finally, you also need to supply a label for 0, since that is a break as well. It's always good to supply both the breaks and labels. You shouldn't supply the breaks as a character vector, as it is a continuous scale.